# Snake animation

Tags: python, animation, tkinter

I got a homework for my coding class and im not sure how to do it. I am supposed to make an animation that would light up the squares in a sort of snake type animation (it starts in top left square, continues to top right, then goes to second line but instead of starting on right side, it starts on left side). How should I do it? Please help me, I'm clueless. Below is the code I've got so far.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


master = tk.Tk()
rectangle_list = []
canvas_width = 280
canvas_height = 250
w = tk.Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
w.pack()
input1 = tk.Entry (master)
w.create_window(100, 40, window=input1)

for i in range(11):
    x = i * 25
    if i == 1:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(0, 0, 25, 25, fill="grey"))
    else:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(x-25, 0, x, 25, fill="grey"))

for i in range(11):
    x = i * 25
    if i == 1:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(0, 25, 25, 50, fill="grey"))
    else:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(x-25, 25, x, 50, fill="grey"))

for i in range(11):
    x = i * 25
    if i == 1:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(0, 50, 25, 75, fill="grey"))
    else:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(x-25, 50, x, 75, fill="grey"))

for i in range(11):
    x = i * 25
    if i == 1:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(0, 75, 25, 100, fill="grey"))
    else:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(x-25, 75, x, 100, fill="grey"))

for i in range(11):
    x = i * 25
    if i == 1:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(0, 100, 25, 125, fill="grey"))
    else:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(x-25, 100, x, 125, fill="grey"))

for i in range(11):
    x = i * 25
    if i == 1:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(0, 125, 25, 150, fill="grey"))
    else:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(x-25, 125, x, 150, fill="grey"))

for i in range(11):
    x = i * 25
    if i == 1:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(0, 150, 25, 175, fill="grey"))
    else:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(x-25, 150, x, 175, fill="grey"))

for i in range(11):
    x = i * 25
    if i == 1:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(0, 175, 25, 200, fill="grey"))
    else:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(x-25, 175, x, 200, fill="grey"))

for i in range(11):
    x = i * 25
    if i == 1:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(0, 200, 25, 225, fill="grey"))
    else:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(x-25, 200, x, 225, fill="grey"))

for i in range(11):
    x = i * 25
    if i == 1:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(0, 225, 25, 250, fill="grey"))
    else:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(x-25, 225, x, 250, fill="grey"))

# manage color change loop based on index of rectangle list
def uno(ndex=0):
    if ndex < len(rectangle_list):
        w.itemconfig(rectangle_list[ndex], fill='red')
        master.after(100, uno, ndex+1)


def dos(ndex=0):
    if ndex < len(rectangle_list):
        w.itemconfig(rectangle_list[ndex], fill='grey')
        master.after(0, dos, ndex+1)

def tres(ndex=0):
    if ndex < len(rectangle_list):
        w.itemconfig(rectangle_list[ndex], fill='red')
        master.after(100, tres, ndex-1)

def quatros(ndex=0):
    if ndex < len(rectangle_list):
       w.itemconfig(rectangle_list[ndex], fill='red')
       master.after(100, tres, ndex-6)
    if ndex < len(rectangle_list):
        w.itemconfig(rectangle_list[ndex], fill='red')
        master.after(100, uno, ndex+6)

def cinq(ndex=0):
    if ndex < len(rectangle_list):
       w.itemconfig(rectangle_list[ndex], fill='red')
       master.after(100, tres, ndex-1)
    if ndex < len(rectangle_list):
        w.itemconfig(rectangle_list[ndex], fill='red')
        master.after(100, uno, ndex+1)

def six(ndex=0):
    while True:
        if ndex == len(rectangle_list):
            w.itemconfig(rectangle_list[ndex], fill='red')
            master.after(10, six, ndex+random.choice(rectangle_list))

def seven(ndex=0):
    if ndex < len(rectangle_list):
        w.itemconfig(rectangle_list[ndex], fill='red')
        master.after(100, seven, ndex+3)

tk.Button(master, text="animacia", command=uno).pack(side='left', padx=10)
tk.Button(master, text="zhasni", command=dos).pack(side='left', padx=10)
tk.Button(master, text="animacia 2", command=tres).pack(side='left', padx=10)
tk.Button(master, text="animacia 3", command=quatros).pack(side='left', padx=10)
tk.Button(master, text="animacia 4", command=cinq).pack(side='left', padx=10)
tk.Button(master, text="animacia 5", command=six).pack(side='left', padx=10)
tk.Button(master, text="animacia 6", command=seven).pack(side='left', padx=10)
master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to alternate your `range` function with `range(11)` and `range(10,0,-1)`:

```
for i in range(11):
    x = i * 25
    if i == 1:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(0, 0, 25, 25, fill="grey"))
    else:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(x-25, 0, x, 25, fill="grey"))

for i in range(10,0,-1):
    x = i * 25
    if i == 1:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(0, 25, 25, 50, fill="grey"))
    else:
        rectangle_list.append(w.create_rectangle(x-25, 25, x, 50, fill="grey"))

...
```

But you should really consider minimizing repetitive code in your multiple `for` loops.

Comment: thank you, also would there be a way to make it light up from top to bottom instead of left to right?

Comment: Your current approach is lighting up from the sequence of the rectangles inserted into the list `rectangle_list`. You can change it to any way you want by adjusting the way you create your rectangles. But what I really recommend is to keep your rectangles in a list of lists instead which you can treat as a matrix and easily manipulate.